# PHP MYSQL выборка дочерних элементов, не удаленного родителя

Tags: mysql

Есть базовая таблица древа комментариев:

```
comments:
id | comment | parent | display
1  | lol     | null   | 1
2  | lol     | 1      | 1
```

Я хотел бы попросить помощи, в составлении запроса. Допустим я удалил комментарий с айди 1 (обновил поле `display = 0`).

Во время выборки комментариев из бд, присутствует условие `WHERE display = 1`, чтобы не выбирать удаленные данные. Так вот, как сделать так, чтобы не выбирались комментарии, где комментарий с айди текущего родителя, имеет `display = 0`? То есть удалил я первый комментарий, после чего  второй и все для кого он является родителем, выборке не подлежат.

Comment: а просто при удалении сразу пройдись и удали всё дерево, а не только родителя

Comment: @Blacknife нет нужды, прикрепил ответ в котором одним запросом можно выбрать не удаленных родителей, а так же элементы, родители которых не удалены.

Comment: смотри сам, что лучше - сделать один раз что-то сложное при удалении, или хоть и немного но заставлять тужиться БД при каждом запросе

Comment: говоря проще, данные читаются значительно чаще, чем записываются

Comment: @Blacknife мне кажется оптимизированнее выбирать сразу родителей + дочерних с не удаленными родителями, нежели трогать все поля при удалении

Comment: @Blacknife думаю ты прав, стоит выводить по дисплею 1, без лишних критерий запроса.

Comment: Я полагаю все дерево строится на стороне php. Может будет быстрей просто в php выкидывать данные удаленного родителя.

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался, может кому будет полезно -

```
"SELECT * FROM comments WHERE ((parent IS NULL AND display = 1) 
OR (parent IN(SELECT id FROM comments WHERE parent IS NULL AND display = 1)) AND display = 1) 
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10"
```

То есть вначале мы берем всех родителей (где парент = 0) и которые не удалены, затем мы выбираем все дочерние элементы где парент совпадает с родителем который не удален (дисплей = 1)

Comment: А что будет, если уровень вложенности больше 2-х.